# OSMNX produces a nearest node to a point which seems too far

Tags: python, osmnx

I am trying to calculate the shortest path between few points. As the first step, I tried to find the nearest node to my origin point (centroid of my case study area) that is green in the pic below. However, the nearest node, shown in red, is 35786.63 meter away which is quite far.
Am I doing something wrong or the algorithm is not really finding the nearest node?
Here is the reproducible code.

*********  EDITED ****************

```
import osmnx as ox  
Center_point = (-4.409442937827447, 15.354357144163854)
G_Centre = ox.graph_from_point(Center_point, dist=10000, simplify=True, dist_type='bbox', network_type='drive', clean_periphery=False)
G_Centre_proj_Consol_EN = ox.project_graph(G_Centre, to_crs='epsg:32733')
Centre_EN = (539315.4163772659, 9512605.079423266)
G_Centre_origin, G_Centre_distance = ox.get_nearest_node(G_Centre_proj_Consol_EN, Centre_EN, method='haversine',return_dist=True)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using a projected graph and `method='haversine'`: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.get_nearest_node

Comment: I first used euclidean as per the guideline but it returns a node which was 0 and it was even further than the one produced by haversine method.

Comment: I tried a fudge which is working but still can't understand why finding the single node is not returning the expected result. The trick is to replicate the points and then use the other command which is for list of nodes. Since all the results are the same, just use one for the next step.     `Bounds_E = (Centre_EN[0],) * 3
Bounds_N = (Centre_EN[1],) * 3` and 
`G_Centre_origin = ox.distance.get_nearest_nodes(G_Centre_proj_Consol_EN, Bounds_E, Bounds_N, method='kdtree')`

Comment: There's a *lot* going on in your code right now. If you simplify it down to a *minimal* reproducible example I can take a look.

Comment: I edited and reduced it to few lines. You can check the results of both methods and see what they return.

Comment: @gboeing: Any chance to have a look at the code and see why the euclidean method is not working?

Comment: Same as before:  you're using a projected graph and method='haversine'. This will give you incorrect results, as stated in the docs.